# Input Filter in R

Tags: r, shiny

I have a data set named "a2". Sample Data

```
CID  Store  Distance
1     X      2
2     Y      3
2     S      5
1     A      1
3     B      10
```

I want to develop an app in shiny with three tabs Filter Value, Nearest Store, Nearest Client. So whatever user chooses as an input so it should display all the rows of input.

So in Filter Value Tab
Ex if i choose CID 3 then it should extract only rows having CID3.

So in Nearest Store Tab
Ex if i choose Store X then it should extract only rows having Store X.

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Lat Long Address Mapping in R"),
    fluidRow(
      mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",    
                    tabPanel("FilterValue", 
                             selectInput('InputID', 'ID', choices=NULL, selected=NULL),
                             ),

                    tabPanel("Nearest Store", 
                             selectInput('InputStore', 'ID', choices=NULL, selected=NULL),
                    ),                    

                    tabPanel("Nearest Client", 
                             selectInput('InputCustomer', 'ID', choices=NULL, selected=NULL),
                    ) 

                        ))))
  ,
  server = function(input, output,session) {
    output$FilterValue<- renderDataTable(a2)    
    updateSelectizeInput(session, 'InputID',
                         choices = a2$CID,
                         server = TRUE)

    updateSelectizeInput(session, 'InputStore',
                         choices = a2$Store,
                         server = TRUE)

    updateSelectizeInput(session, 'InputCustomer',
                         choices = a2$CID,
                         server = TRUE)

    output$Nearest Client<- renderDataTable({
      paste(input$InputCustomer)

    })

    })
```

However in Nearest Client Tab I want to have two filters one of CID and one of distance

So if choose CID1 and minimum distance 2 it should give me only 1 row.

My output is generating all data of a2 in tab FIlter Value and Nearest Store. I am stuck with Nearest Client Tab

Thanks

**Leaflet**

Data frame is a

Sample Data is as follows

```
ID    Lat        Long   Address  
1   12.904249 77.70253    1/2 CA    
2   21.221475 72.81281    2/3 DC  
3   23.039251 72.58388    3/5 HJ
```

library (leaflet)

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Lat Long Address Mapping in R"),
    fluidRow(
      mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                    tabPanel("Map", 
                             bootstrapPage(
                               tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
                               leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "100%"),
                               absolutePanel(
                                 top = 80,
                                 left = 30,

                               )
                             )
                    )
  ,
  server = function(input, output,session) {
    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
        leaflet(a) %>%
          addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
          addMarkers(lng = ~Long, lat = ~Lat,
                     popup = ~address)})
```

When I run this standalone it works

```
leaflet(a) %>%
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
  addMarkers(lng = ~Long, lat = ~Lat,
             popup = ~address)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the data as reactive and filter them it with dplyr

```
a2 %>% filter(CID == input$InputID & Distance == input$InputCustomer)
```

This will do what you want in the last tab. The code you gave also has issues like no output for the data tables you want to render and so on.I tried not to change too much on the way you constructed it but there are better ways to build the app. Below is a working example of what I think you are asking for:

```
 a2 <- data.frame(CID = c(1,2,2,1,3),
                 Store = c("X", "Y", "S", "A", "B"),
                 Distance = c(2,3,5,1,10), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)



    library(shiny)
    library(dplyr)
    library(DT)
    ui <- fluidPage(
      fluidRow(
        mainPanel(
          tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",    
                      tabPanel("FilterValue", value = "filtervalue",
                               selectInput('InputID', 'ID', choices=NULL, selected=NULL),
                               dataTableOutput("out1")
                      ),

                      tabPanel("Nearest Store", value = "neareststore",
                               selectInput('InputStore', 'ID', choices=NULL, selected=NULL),
                               dataTableOutput("out2")
                      ),                    

                      tabPanel("Nearest Client", value = "nearestclient",
                               selectInput('InputCustomer', 'ID', choices=NULL, selected=NULL),
                               dataTableOutput("out3")
                      ) 

          )))
    )

    server <- function(input, output, session) {
      filtout <- reactive({
        a3 <- a2 %>% filter(CID == input$InputID)
        return(a3)
      })
      output$out1 <- DT::renderDataTable(datatable(filtout(), options = list(searching = F,
                                                                             pageLength = 20,
                                                                             lengthMenu = c(5, 10, 15, 20), 
                                                                             scrollX = T,
                                                                             autoWidth = TRUE
      )))
      storeout <- reactive({
        a3 <- a2 %>% filter(Store == input$InputStore)
        return(a3)
      })

      output$out2 <- DT::renderDataTable(datatable(storeout(), options = list(searching = F,
                                                                             pageLength = 20,
                                                                             lengthMenu = c(5, 10, 15, 20), 
                                                                             scrollX = T,
                                                                             autoWidth = TRUE
      )))

      custout <- reactive({
        a3 <- a2 %>% filter(CID == input$InputID & Distance == input$InputCustomer)
        return(a3)
      })

      output$out3 <- DT::renderDataTable(datatable(custout(), options = list(searching = F,
                                                                              pageLength = 20,
                                                                              lengthMenu = c(5, 10, 15, 20), 
                                                                              scrollX = T,
                                                                              autoWidth = TRUE
      )))

      updateSelectizeInput(session, 'InputID',
                           choices = a2$CID,
                           server = TRUE)

      updateSelectizeInput(session, 'InputStore',
                           choices = a2$Store,
                           server = TRUE)

      updateSelectizeInput(session, 'InputCustomer',
                           choices = a2$Distance,
                           server = TRUE)


      output$nearestclient<- renderDataTable({
        paste(input$InputCustomer)

      })
    }

    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

New info:

So I found out the issue was the cardDB.postitron. I changed the map to what I use normally. Also I had to strip some of the UI to get it the principle working and adress variable was not provided but this should form the basis of what you need.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                  tabPanel(title = "Map",
                           leafletOutput("map")
                  )))))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(a) %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.WorldGrayCanvas,
                       options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)) %>%
      addMarkers(lng = ~Long, lat = ~Lat,
                 popup = ~address)
})
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Super Gandalf..Thanks a ton Super like

Comment: Anytime, glad I could help.

Comment: I need one more help with leaflet map in shiny..when i run standalone it works and map is visible but when put with shiny it doesnot give me any output. If you can help me with it..code is ready

Comment: No promises, but I'll see what I can do

Comment: shall i post a separate or edit this. I am editing this post my comments below and it will start with bold.

Comment: sort of close to what you would like to achieve in the answer